# PHP - How to sort the same array multiple times?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, ksort

I am trying to make a simple script that will first put an array() into function so I can call on it multiple times to sort. Here is what my array looks like:

```
// I want this inside of a function so I can call on it:

$a = array(
    15 => "C",
    12 => "E",
    11 => "B",
    19 => "P",
    10 => "L",
    14 => "N",
    20 => "A"    
 );

// This is how I brought it into a function and formatted it:

function original_array($a){ 
    foreach($a as $key => $types) {
        print $key . " " . ":" . " " . $types . "<br />";
    }
}
```

I then just have to call original_array() and it prints out fine, but if I sort it once I cant sort it again. It will just print out the first sort:

```
// Print out array is is:

original_array();

// Then I print out array with sort():

sort($a);
original_array($a);

// But if I try and sort it again with different sort it doesn't work:

ksort($a);
original_array($a);
```

What am I doing wrong? I am somewhat new to PHP so your help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE://**

This is what I ended up doing. I should have read up on sort function a little more thoroughly. I was unaware that it destroyed the original pointers.

```
<?php  
// Original array: 
$a = array(
    15 => "C",
    12 => "E",
    11 => "B",
    19 => "P",
    10 => "L",
    14 => "N",
    20 => "A"   
);

// Array for sort() function:
$b = $a

function print_format($array){ 
    foreach($array as $key => $types) {
        print $key . " " . "=>" . " " . $types . "<br />";
    }
}    


print "Original";  
print_format($a);     

print "sort()";
sort($b);
print_format($b);

print "ksort()";
ksort($a);
print_format($a);    

print "asort()";
asort($a);  
print_format($a);    

print "krsort()";
krsort($a);  
print_format($a);

print "rsort()";
rsort($b);  
print_format($b);    

print "arsort()";
arsort($a);  
print_format($a);
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

The normal `sort()` function destroys the keys for all values, so when it's sorted, each key is now numeric `0, 1, 2, 3`. Therefore when you use `ksort()`, it does nothing because they're already numerically sorted by key.

Try using [`asort()`](http://php.net/asort) to maintain key => value association when sorting by value. Then when you use `ksort()` later on, the keys still exist so you can sort in that way.

Comment: This helped immensely. sort() function through me off. I didn't understand why the others were working but they wouldn't if sort() was before them.

Answer (score -1):

You can use reset()  function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php

Comment: I have tried the reset. It may of been where I placed it, but it did not work.

Comment: my answer is signed as unused by someone. But I offered my option only. Can you use $b=$a; and after each sort($b) call $a again with ($b=$a) therefore $a will be remained as before.

Comment: That worked perfectly! So by assigning it to a new variable as stated ($b = $a) basically creates a new array that is unmodified?

Comment: Ok. But I loosed some points because of negative pointing. Please accept mine answer.